# Keeping items in cart for logged in users on their log off and cart of user could not be seen by others on logoff

Tags: php, html, css, session, cookies

I have a WordPress website and we want that if someone browses the website and adds some items to the cart then log in while checkout or vice versa. In case the user logs off or closes the browser then those items should remain in the cart for that particular login only until the order has been completed or has been removed by the customer from the cart.
We want that if the user logs off from the website then if someone else sits on his pc and browses the same website then the other person could not see what the user had in his cart. It can only be viewable once the user logs in back.
Could you please suggest the best way to achieve this target?
Thanks!

Comment: If the user is not logged in, store the cart in local storage (in the browser using JS). When the user logs in and have products in their cart, put that cart in your database with that user id and clear the local storage. Then the cart will only be accessible for that user when they are logged in. Since the question is a bit too high level, that's about as specific I can be with a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Hmm, you are correct. We will see if this could help.